# Setdate onSelect Datepicker

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker

Can I `setDate` of another text element when the `onSelect` event fires on the first text element?

I tried coding it this way, it didn't work:

```
$( "#datebilled" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        if ($('#cat option:selected').text() == "ABC") {
            var date_billed = $('#datebilled').datepicker('getDate');
            var date_overdue = new Date();
            var weekDays = AddBusinessDays(45);

            date_overdue.setDate(date_billed.getDate() + weekDays);
            date_overdue = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date_overdue);

            //setDate of date overdue
            $('#datepd').datepicker('setDate', date_overdue);


        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [**onSelect**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       $("#ElemID").val(dateText);

   }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4H44/1/)

Comment: I tried this but I was getting an error when I had to calculate the difference between this text element [whose date was set as you have shown -- adding 30 business days] and the datepicker text element [date selected from datepicker].